# Error on GTID Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave, slave

During the replication usind GTID, happened this error in the slave server:

Error 'Cannot execute statements with implicit commit inside a transaction when @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT != AUTOMATIC or @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT_LIST != NULL.' on query. Default database: ''. Query: 'flush privileges'

Somebody can help me?

Thanks for all! (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

you must check GTID_NEXT variables.it should by AUTOMATIC.if it is not then set it to AUTOMATIC.then there is not an issue with implict commit command in GTID Based Replication.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed running with change master to (Relay_Master_Log_File & Exec_Master_Log_Pos from show slave status).   There some blockers are exisits using gtid.  Error 1178 is one of it

Answer (score 0):

You can reset slave from same position :

```
stop slave;
reset slave;

change master to
 MASTER_HOST='192.168XX',
 MASTER_USER='XX',
 MASTER_PASSWORD='XX',
 MASTER_PORT=3306,
 MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.XX',
 MASTER_LOG_POS=XX;

show slave status ;
start slave ;
```